# jquery mobile ui-btn-active doesn't work

Tags: jquery, mobile, tabs

In jQuery mobile I have tabs bar with three values, when i switch between the categories it just light a second

i want when i click on any tab, the tab will be set active with different color

i use this jQuery code :

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-navbar ul li > a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.ui-navbar').find('a').removeClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
    //$('.ui-navbar ul li > a').removeClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
    //$('.content_div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show().siblings('.content_div').hide();
});
```

Html :

```
 <div class="boxshadow" >

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li ><a href="javascript:;" data-href="a" data-theme="a"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" class="ui-navbar-btn-active">Shopping</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-href="b" data-theme="a">
                Entertainment</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" data-href="c" data-theme="a">Restaurants</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the .ui-state-persist class, you're are telling jQuery Mobile to make the li tag active no matter what page you navigate to. So your jQuery script is defeating the purpose

Nix the jquery script and the .ui-state-persist class and assign a background-color to the .ui-btn-active class like so

```
[data-theme="b"].ui-btn-active { background: none 0 0 no-repet #whatever-color; }
```

If you have multiple page structure (http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/#Multi-pagetemplatestructure) , the navbar should take care of the active state automatically.